# Existence of Parentheses after the new, make any different in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11

Look at the tow declarations bellow. These two method make any different in **C++ 11**? I checked the story about C++03 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620137/do-the-parentheses-after-the-type-name-make-a-difference-with-new)

`Class A{int m;}`

1. `A* a = new A`
2. `A* a = new A();`

Answer (score 9):

It's the same in C++11 as it was in C++03.

The first is *default-initialision*, leaving `m` uninitialised.

The second is *value-initialisation*, initialising `m` to zero.

If the class had a user-provided default constructor, then both would do the same thing, calling that constructor.